# could not locate file in lookup: ansible ssh key adding failed

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

```
name: copy public keys to users- for other environments

  authorized_key: user={{ item.username }}

   key="{{ lookup('file', '../files/{{ item.username }}.pub') }}"

   path='/home/{{ item.username }}/.ssh/authorized_keys'

  manage_dir=no

  with_items:

  - { username: 'xxxxxxxx' }
  - { username: 'xxxxxxxx' }
  - { username: 'xxxxxxxx' }
```

Getting following error while running the above ansible code.

```
fatal: [xxxxxx.xxxx.com] => Failed to template user={{ item.username }} 

key="{{ lookup('file', '../files/{{ item.username }}.pub') }}": could not
 locate file in lookup: ../files/{{ item.username }}.pub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use nested Jinja2 expressions. Just use variable name as is:

```
{{ lookup('file', '../files/'+item.username+'.pub') }}
```